# Facing Ambiguous Reference to SQL Error in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing below Error in my Spark scala code ...

error: reference to sql is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import org.apache.spark._
and import sqlContext.{sql, table}

Below are the API's i am trying to import.

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.spark_partition_id
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{trim,ltrim,rtrim,col}
```

Failure is at where i create temporary table or view and write SQL on top of it...

createOrReplaceTempView

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Where do you import the sqlContext? I don't see

```
import sqlContext.{sql, table}
```

in case you want to avoid naming conflict you can always do:

```
org.apache.spark.{sql => whatever_you_want_to_name}
```

but I doubt if you are importing the right package since normally sqlContext.sql is rarely used if you are using  org.apache.spark.sql